# javascript dropdown validation

Tags: javascript, validation

I need to alert if you haven't selected anything and couldn't get it to work. It needs to show what is where wrong and alert with a window.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<select id="ddlView">
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value="1">test1</option>
<option value="2">test2</option>
<option value="3">test3</option>
</select>  
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="select" />

<script>
function Validate()
{
var e = document.getElementById("ddlView");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

var strUser1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
if(strUser==0)
{
alert("Please select a user");
}
}
</td></head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you have multiple problems here.

1. You need to add a body tag
2. Set the correct function name in your button.
3. you need a closing script tag

Give this a try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <select id="ddlView">
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            <option value="1">test1</option>
            <option value="2">test2</option>
            <option value="3">test3</option>
        </select>  
        <input type="button" onclick="Validate()" value="select" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Validate()
            {
                var e = document.getElementById("ddlView");
                var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

                var strUser1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
                if(strUser==0)
                {
                    alert("Please select a user");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not you asked for but you can still consider what i did.
Have an **option** with value **0** which is going to be the default option of the dropdown and add **required** attribute to the **select** element.
Once this **select** element is in a **form** and is submitted ,**HTML** is automatically going to take over the validation part.

```
<select required>
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="1">Option1</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
<div>
    <span>Select the course : </span>
    <select id="ddlView">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">Java Script</option>
        <option value="2">CSS</option>
        <option value="3">JQuery</option>
        <option value="3">HTML</option>
        <option value="3">C#</option>
    </select>
</div>
<br >
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" onclick="ddlValidate();" />
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ddlValidate() {
        var e = document.getElementById("ddlView");
        var optionSelIndex = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var optionSelectedText = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        if (optionSelIndex == 0) {
            alert("Please select a Course");
        }
        else {
            alert("Success !! You have selected Course : " + optionSelectedText); ;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: More explanation of how your code differs from OP and why that makes it work may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

That has to be in your form processing script, you can just add it to the top of your code and check if it has been submitted.

```
// Place this atop of your script.
if(isset($_POST)) {
    if($_POST['member_id']) {
        // Your codes here
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no mention of PHP in the question (or tags or in the provided code)

Answer (score 0):

call this function at a button click`(OnClientClick=" return Validate()")`  you have to list an item for the 0'th positions(`ddlView.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select...", "0"));`)

```
function Validate(){
    var region = document.getElementById('<%=ddlView.ClientID%>').value;
                   if (region == 0) {
                       alert("Please select a user");
                       return false;
                   }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, I do not believe it is necessary to alert. You can simply use the `required` HTML attribute in the `select` tag and make `selected` one option by default, `disable` it, set the `value=''`, and set the `button type=submit`. In this case, the form won't be submitted if there is no selection by the user.

```html
<form>
  <label for="ddlView">Select an Option</label>
  <select id="ddlView" required>
    <option selected disabled value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2">test2</option>
    <option value="3">test3</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```